# Angular get count of word file pages

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I get the total count of word doc/docs pages? , I already get the count of PDF file but I want to do the same for docs or ppt

```
  getPageCount(event) {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(event.target.files[0]);
    fileReader.onloadend = () => {
        const count = (fileReader.result as string).match(/\/Type[\s]*\/Page[^s]/g).length;
        console.log('Number of Pages:', count);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I've seen someone who selling a script to get docs pages count, you have to think more before you post any comments

Comment: https://codecanyon.net/item/word-docx-doc-proccessing-document-pages-count-words-count-angular-9-net-core/27755257

Answer (score 0):

DOCuments that free flow do not need to store a number of pages until after printing, this is the reason ONE PAGE html files cannot be described as total print pages since it will change AFTER printing when the margins / heading /footings are set and the page scale and shape are defined.

A DOC file may be printed as 10 x A5 landscape or 5 x A4 portrait, thus no need to store an unknown. At best you might get any stored previous user prior printing run setting, but that does not say what it will be on opening in a default reader view.

PDF is fixed media thus the pages should be well defined before construction for reading or printing, but same as flowing pages it is possible to set them to different at print time.

With dynamic XFA.pdf the number of pages can be varied by the viewer thus again no guarantee that a nominal stored value is the finial (upper finished) number of pages.